# File not found error in SharePoint 2010 while using a site template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm using SharePoint 2010. I saved a Site Template(.stp) and used this template to create a sub site. Browser shows file not found error, however, if I add /_layouts/ChageSiteMasterPage.aspx to that URL, I'm able to see settings Page.

Error:
cannot create folder "Path".

Correlation ID: 4baa2636-0dd9-4965-afc1-e438d74a20d5

What could be the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Search for that correlation ID in your SharePoint log. Probably the problem is because you need to activate a feature in the new site, or you have a custom solution that you need to deploy there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Site Setting and open the Master Pages section.  Look for anything checked out and chack it back in.  This happens each time you create a new site from a template.